# ORDS Rest API for handling queries involving JOIN across multiple tables in Oracle

Tags: rest

ORDS enables the Oracle database objects as REST API on which CRUD operations can be performed. However I would like to understand is there any provision there to handle the queries involving multiple tables such as JOINS.

For example, say I have a query like this:

```
select empname from employee e,dept d where e.deptid=d.deptid and deptname='IT';
```

Below is the table meta-data:

```
employee:
empid
empname
deptid

dept:
deptid
deptname
```

Is there any REST url exposed via ORDS which will cater to this join?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use the formatting options to highlight your post in more readable format.

Answer (score 1):

I use this SQL

```
select * from employees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id;
```

And create New Module in REST Data Services and Upload it

you can follow the steps from here : [Docs REST FROM oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e87809/getting-started-with-RESTful-services.htm#AELIG-GUID-4F651A96-1E4F-4048-AE70-3136AC2A409A)

its works fine, heres my result : 
http://haidar.id:8080/ords/hr/test/employees/

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with the needed join and enable the view for auto REST.